# Android SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am not sure why my code isn't working, following the android developer guide this should work. I assume that it is because I don't have a preferences file created, I am not sure how to go about that. Could someone take a look and see if I have written everything correctly?

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "TestPrefs";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void Save(View v){
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    final EditText s = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    settings.edit().putString("TBox1", s.getText().toString());
    settings.edit().commit();
}

public void Open(View v){
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    final EditText s = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String newS = settings.getString("TBox1", "");
    s.setText(newS);
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be in the save code, because I always get the default value for TBox1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `commit()` on the same Editor. Commiting on another object as you have done means that the previous `putString()` gets lost. This means change

```
settings.edit().putString("TBox1", s.getText().toString());
settings.edit().commit();
```

to

```
settings.edit().putString("TBox1", s.getText().toString()).commit();
```

Of course, if you have more than one thing to edit, you can keep a reference to your editor:

Eg:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("key1", "value1");
editor.putString("key2", "value2");
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you, I imagined it was something simple.